# Spring Boot app does not launch in Eclipse using Spring Boot Dashboard

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I use Eclipse and the Spring Boot Dashboard to launch my applications.

I noticed that when I debug the app and does not terminate the app properly I can't run it from the dahsboard. I also cannot launch it as Java Application.

The console prints the following:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-03-26 16:39:36.323  INFO 11672 --- [           main] portfolio.Application                    : Starting Application on Computer-PC with PID 11672 (D:\Dev\workspace_eclipse\portfolio\target\classes started by User1 in D:\Dev\workspace_eclipse\portfolio)
2016-03-26 16:39:36.326  INFO 11672 --- [           main] portfolio.Application                    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-03-26 16:39:36.671  INFO 11672 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1b68b9a4: startup date [Sat Mar 26 16:39:36 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-26 16:39:37.860  INFO 11672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-03-26 16:39:38.823  WARN 11672 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2016-03-26 16:39:38.845  WARN 11672 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
2016-03-26 16:39:38.852 ERROR 11672 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at portfolio.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap.handleDeployment(Bootstrap.java:62) ~[undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.18.Final.jar:1.3.18.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.18.Final.jar:1.3.18.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:152) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.18.Final.jar:1.3.18.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:365) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:220) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted

2016-03-26 16:39:38.853  INFO 11672 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/Dev/workspace_eclipse/portfolio/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.8.4.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.3.3/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.6/groovy-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/2.2.1/jquery-2.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-undertow/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-undertow-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.3.18.Final/undertow-core-1.3.18.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-api/3.3.4.Final/xnio-api-3.3.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.4.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-servlet/1.3.18.Final/undertow-servlet-1.3.18.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/1.3.18.Final/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.18.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/websocket/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec/1.1.0.Final/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/User1/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.0/javax.el-3.0.0.jar]
```

It was working, and stopeed working just after the execution was terminated.

The weird thing is: if I try to run as Maven spring-boot:run it works fine.

I tried to Project/Clean and start Eclipse with -clean argument.

Comment: post pom.xml is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this pom.xml or refactor with this dependency

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and knowledge include here how to use tomcat with undertow  : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I'm still confused on why it was working and suddenly stopped after a "Terminate" in debug session though.

Comment: what a getting console

Comment: terminate mostly you try run when app is still runnig or embeded tomcat not include in your pom.xml